# Why i'm getting exception out of memory when trying to display images in pictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
int countFiles = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ff[countFiles]);
    countFiles++;
}
```

ff is a List contain 40 files.
The timer interval is set to 1000ms.

The exception is on the line:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ff[countFiles]);

  System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024882
  Message=Out of memory.
  Source=System.Drawing
```

Comment: You need to dispose the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to release previous image from memory try this:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(pictureBox1.Image != null)
            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ff[countFiles]);
        countFiles++;
    }
```